# Is exporting of smart (single) quotes broken in Org 8.3?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I cannot seem to get correctly exported smart single quotes in Org 8.3.

Here is a minimal `test.org` file:

```
#+OPTIONS: ':t
#+LANGUAGE: en

This is 'within single quotes'.  This is "within double quotes".
```

With `emacs -Q`, `org-version` reports 8.2.10.  The output when exporting to UTF-8 text is:

> This is ‘within single quotes’.  This is “within double quotes”.

and the output when exporting to LaTeX is:

```
This is `within single quotes'.  This is ``within double quotes''.
```

This is what I would expect.

If I load the most recent version of org-mode (starting from `emacs -Q`, typing `M-x package-initialize RET`, and `M-x load-library RET org RET`), then `org-version` reports `8.3.2`, and the output no longer correctly translates single quotes.  In UTF-8 text, the result is:

> This is ’within single quotes’.  This is “within double quotes”.

and in LaTeX, the result is:

```
This is 'within single quotes'.  This is ``within double quotes''.
```

Is there anything non-obvious going on with smart quote export in the newer version of Org, or is this simply a bug which I should report?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I suspect it lies in `org-export--smart-quote-status`.

Comment: You can do `M-x org-submit-bug-report`

Comment: any update on this?  could you post a link to the bug report?

Comment: @Mark I know this is several years later, but for people how arrive here by searching for this, let me say than Jon [did post to the mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-10/msg00174.html) and was told that there was a change in Org mode: it was decided that single quotes would only export smartly when they were nested inside double quotes. (So it's not a bug but a conscious choice.)

Comment: @Omar, thanks for the information. A decision like that should really be left up to users.  In some English writing styles, single quotes are the primary quoting mechanism.